# got this error on flutter "The argument type 'AuthCredential' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PhoneAuthCredential'."

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been making a mobile verification page using firebase authentication and I got this error
"The argument type 'AuthCredential' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PhoneAuthCredential'.".
Please help me I have been trying to find a solution for this for the past 2 days.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
'Home_Screen.dart';

enum MobileVerificationState {
  SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE,
  SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE,
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  MobileVerificationState currentState =
      MobileVerificationState.SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE;

  final phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final otpController = TextEditingController();

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late String verificationId;

  bool showLoading = false;

      void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(
      PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
    setState(() {
      showLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final authCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

      if(authCredential.user != null){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));
      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Login failed")));
    }
  }

  getMobileFormWidget(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        TextField(
          controller: phoneController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Phone Number",
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              showLoading = true;
            });

            await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: phoneController.text,
              verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                });
                //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
              },
              verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                });
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Login             failed")));
          },
              codeSent: (verificationId, resendingToken) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                  currentState = MobileVerificationState.SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE;
                  this.verificationId = verificationId;
                });
              },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) async {},
            );
          },
          child: Text("SEND"),
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }

  getOtpFormWidget(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        TextField(
          controller: otpController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Enter OTP",
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
                PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                    verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: otpController.text);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(**phoneAuthCredential**);
          },
          child: Text("VERIFY"),
          
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }
                                                                                                              
                                                             ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
```

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to pass `AuthCredential` as `PhoneAuthCredential` in the following code:

```
getOtpFormWidget(context) {
    ...
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
                PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                    verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: otpController.text);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential); // this line
          },
          child: Text("VERIFY"),
          
        ),
...
    );
```

**Solution**
As described in the exception, You have typecasted `PhoneAuthCredential` to `AuthCredential` in this line:

```
AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
                PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                    verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: otpController.text);
```

Meaning you have supercast it to `AuthCredential` explicitly, which dart can not downcast automatically to `PhoneAuthCredential` when you send it to `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` method.

**Solution**

Just remove the type of `phoneAuthCredential`. Replace it with `final` or set it to it's original type `PhoneAuthCredential`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Harshvardhan joshi sir

```
  TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
          final  AuthCredential  =
                PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                   verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: otpController.text);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential();
          },
          child: Text("VERIFY"),
          
        ),
```

what argument should I add to "signInWithPhoneCredential"?